# How to create a refence a generic class in a non generic class

Tags: c#, generics, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

is there a way of referencing a generic class in a non generic class e.g

```
public class IGenericClass<T> where T: class
{
}

public class GenericClass<T> : IGenericClass<T> where T : class
{   }
```

how best do i create a refence for the IGenericClass in a concrete class.

thanks for your assistance

Comment: You need to specify the type `public class GenericClass : IGenericClass<String> {   }`.

Comment: Side note: Identifiers with an `I` prefix is normally used for interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. However, it should be a closed constructed type, meaning `T` should be known upfront.

```
class Client
{
    private IGenericClass<T> instance;// Illegal[1]
    private IGenericClass<object> instance;// Legal, It can be any type.
}
```

Also, don't name classes with I Prefix which may give the impression that it is an interface when it is not.

<sub>1. It is legal if you have a type named `T`, otherwise not</sub>

Comment: thanks guys for your assistance. Actually the IGenericClass<T> is an interface. I am trying to implement the Unit of work and Repository pattern i desire to keep the IGenericClass<T> (which is my generic repository ) as generic as possible within my unitofwork. Would that be a good idea.